# Java Transparent Panel Over Another Panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am working with Java 2D graphics and having an issue.

I have a `JPanel` onto which I draw some images and also moving images with a Timer into the circles.

*Initially I draw the interface in `paint()` method. and upon button click I read data from file and then calling a function to display those images and strings in a timed controlled function. 
* The issue is, My Drawing screen showing overlapping images, If I call `repaint()`, the screen start flicking.

I need help with adding the basic drawing as an image in the background Panel and then runtime drawing onto another overlapped but transparent panel so if I call `repaint()` screen behaves normally and no flickering occurs. I am attaching screenshots of the scenario.
[image: Background]
[image: Runtime drawing]

Could anybody suggest how to add two panel so one serves a background and other works like runtime drawing onto background image panel?

Answer (score 3):

I'm hope that there is swing.JPanel not awt.Panel, then to use paintComponent instead of paint

there are four ways

1. add any drawString or subImage/Image inside paintComponent(), prepare those Objects as local variable, inside paintComponent() only use value from these variables or loop inside prepared arrays of Objects
2. add JLabels (transparent, non_opaque by defaulr) with Icons/ImageIcons with text to JLabel, required to add grid of JLabels to JPanel, and on runtime to setIcon/setText to desired JLabel(s)
3. put JLabels to GlassPane, with rest to see in point 2nd
4. put JLabels to JLayer, with rest to see in point 2nd